# Can I format the Y-axis in this way?

Tags: charts, office-for-mac, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm using Excel version 15.15 on a late 2014 Mac Mini running El Capitan 10.11.1.

I am trying to represent 3 things; Profit & Loss for Rates & FX and for Credit (two different asset classes), and a cross-asset Sales Credit number for different banks using a stacked & clustered bar chart.

One of the numbers I need to represent for one of the asset classes at one of the banks is negative (-7).

I ideally would like my Y-axis to go from -20 to 500, with tick marks at -20, 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, and 500, and with the X-axis meeting the Y-axis at 0. I don't need to have labels or tick marks on the X-axis on the graph at all (in case you're thinking the negative bar will overlap with the labels); I'm just going to turn the labels to white and use text boxes... I couldn't work out how to insert dummy data to center the labels on the bars.

Right now I'm stuck with two lesser solutions:

1. The Y-axis ticks are at -20, 80, 180, 280, 380, and 480, with the bars of the graph 'hovering' at 0 above the X-axis, which is set at -20. This leaves a rather unaesthetic gap of white between the X-axis and the bases of all the bars.

2. The Y-axis ticks are at 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, and 500, with the negative PnL number not represented on the graph at all. This is inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat common workaround for a common Excel problem.  I only have Excel 2010, but the solution should be adaptable to your version.  Generally, you'll need to:

1. Create an additional helper series that will be the basis for new gridlines.  You'll be creating an XY/Scatter series, so you'll need your Y Values (as you've already identified, -20, 0, 100...) also, add a second column for their X Values, which will all be 0's.
2. Add this series to your chart (it'll default to a Stacked/Clustered Bar Chart (same as all of your other series).
3. Select just this series and change its Chart Type to XY/Scatter.
4. Adjust your current Y Axis values (i.e. min and max), then turn off lines and labels.
5. Select your XY/Scatter series and add horizontal error bars with an absolute value to match your X Axis.  The error bars become your custom chart lines.
6. Format and label to your taste.

Here's a before (Excel default) and after (Custom) example:

[image]